# File output redirection in Linux

Tags: linux, file-io, filesystems

I have two programs **A** and **B**. I can't change the program **A** - I can only run it with some parameters, but I have written the **B** myself, and I can modify it the way I like.

Program **A** runs for a long time (20-40 hours) and during that time it produces output to the *file*, so that its size increases constantly and can be huge at the end of run (like 100-200 GB). The program **B** then reads the *file* and calculates some stuff. The special property of the *file* is that its content is not correlated: I can divide the file in half and run calculations on each part independently, so that I don't need to store all the data at once: I can calculate on the first part, then throw it away, calculate on the second one, etc.

The problem is that I don't have enough space to store such a big files. I wonder if it is possible to pipe somehow the output of the **A** to **B** without storing all the data at once and without making huge files. Is it possible to do something like that?

Thank you in advance, this is crucial for me now, Roman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If program A supports it, simply pipe.

```
A | B
```

Otherwise, use a fifo.

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
ls -la > /tmp/fifo &
cat /tmp/fifo
```

EDIT: Adjust buffer sizes with ulimit -p and then:

```
cat /tmp/fifo | B
```

Comment: As far as I understand, I will need to sync the output of **B** with **A** reading from it. But the problem is, I don't control the speed of **B** 's execution and **A** sometimes may analyze the output slower than it is produced. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to pipeline output of one program into another.

Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) to know the syntax and know-hows of Unix pipelining.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) which can take stdout and feed it to network and get from network and feed it to stdin

named or unnamed pipe have a problem of small ( 4k ? ) buffer .. that means too many process context switches if you are writing multi gb ...

Or if you are adventurous enough .. you can LD_PRELOAD a so in process A, and trap the open/write calls to do whatever ..